# If women consents to illegal sex and changes her mind during the act, is it rape?

Tags: zina, rape

I have been trying to understand why people in the West who are Muslim say that it's rape no matter if penetration has occurred or not.  If she says stop in the middle and he doesn't they say it's rape?

According to Islam, if a man and women consent to sexual intercourse, they are both intoxicated and they are not married and she changes her mind in the middle of the act, is this rape?

It has always been my understanding through Islam that it is zina and not rape because the actual penetration is already taking place.

Comment: Do you have any references about any scholar or such claiming it to be rape?

Comment: No that's the point, i am being called a rapist sympathizer because i said according to islam this is consensual and they are both guilty of zina, just because she changes her mind doesn't take away from the fact she already consented.

Comment: For instance, if a woman is having sex and she changes her mind in the middle of the act, she screams stop stop stop (and maybe fights back), while the man continues and ignore her, would you call this a rape in your definition or just zina? I ask this because it is important that we define our terms, so we are in the same level. In that definition i think scholars would say it is both zina and rape in the end.

Comment: It is Zina, even if she changes her mind. Calling it Rape or not, that is a totally different point